# Binding combobox inside listview to a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, combobox

Here is my object model

```
private class ShellItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Command { get; set; }

    public List<ShellMenu> ShellMenus { get; private set; }

    public ShellItem()
    {
        ShellMenus = new List<ShellMenu>();
    }
}


public class ShellMenu
{
    public string ExtName;

    public string KeyName;

    public string FileType;

    public string MenuName { get; set; }

    public string Command { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my xaml.

```
<ListView Name="listViewRightClick" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,26.667,107.667" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="600" Header="Command" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Command}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="FileTypes">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ShellMenus}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding MenuName}"
                                          Margin="-6, 0, -6, 0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

My problem is instead of showing MenuName of shellMenu it shows MyNamespace.ShellMenu on every item of combobox.

Comment: I think in this link you can find your answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/5fb63c30-3ce0-406b-b775-875e1250e896

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) is about selection only, use [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) for the display.

```xml
DisplayMemberPath="MenuName"
```

Comment: @RaviPatel: Did you specify a binding instead? It's just a member name.

Comment: It's working now but why we doesn't call it like DisplayMemberPath="Binding MenuName".It's my first day with wpf.

Comment: @RaviPatel: Because it's just how the property is implemented, it even says in the name that it's a *path* to a *member*, read the documention if you don't know how a property works.

Comment: is it possible to add one default value which is selected by default in combo box?

Comment: @RaviPatel: That is different question, which probably has been answered already as well. Have a look around instead of asking me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `DisplayMemberPath` in the `ComboBox`.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ShellMenus}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding MenuName}"
    DisplayMemberPath="MenuName"
    Margin="-6, 0, -6, 0"/>
```